# How to find out which versions of a package can I install on APT

Tags: linux, debian, package-management, repository, apt-get

Using APT, you can install a specific version of a package using:

```
apt-get install package=1.0
```

But you can't do

```
apt-get install package=1.*
```

So, how can I find out which versions are avaliable for `package` on a specific repository, or in all repositories in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885820/how-to-check-the-version-before-install-packages-using-apt-get

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Just as an addendum

```
apt-cache madison <<package name>>
```

will list the versions available from all your sources.

```
apt-cache madison vim
   vim | 2:7.3.547-1 | http://debian.mirrors.tds.net/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
   vim | 2:7.3.429-2 | http://debian.mirrors.tds.net/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
   vim | 2:7.3.429-2 | http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
   vim | 2:7.3.429-2 | http://debian.mirrors.tds.net/debian/ testing/main Sources
   vim | 2:7.3.547-1 | http://debian.mirrors.tds.net/debian/ unstable/main Sources
```

`madison` is an `apt-cache` subcommand, `man apt-cache` says:

> apt-cache's madison command attempts to mimic the output format and a subset of the functionality of the Debian archive management tool, madison. It displays available versions of a package in a tabular format. Unlike the original madison, it can only display information for the architecture for which APT has retrieved package lists (APT::Architecture).

Comment: Madison? Is that a parameter to apt-cache or a package name? I'm not using an apt-get distro anymore (but +1 just in case)

Comment: parameter.  Don't feel bad, it was one of those chance discoveries for me too.  There's a web page (app?) on the Debian site which shows the same information, which I suppose was first, and someone coded it for apt-cache.  Quite handy.

Comment: Wow, quite handy indeed. I'll change the accept to this because it's just what I wanted (at the time) and comes built-in without grepping it.

Comment: This doesn't work for all packages.

Comment: Now THAT is an AWESOME tidbit! tells version and repo, I love it!

Comment: Can you install package for which line ends with `Sources`? How can you do it?

Comment: @nuoritoveri The **Sources** sources are repositories which contain the source code of the various programs and packages.  The source code may be downloaded using the `apt-get source XYZZY` command to download the source for the _XYZZY_ package.  See the _apt-get_ **man page** (`man apt-get`) for more details.

Comment: Really, `madison`? Why not `terry`? Thanks for this

Comment: it's hard to believe there is only 1 version of this package. are we sure the answer is correct? ```apt-cache madison  openssh-client
openssh-client |  1:9.2p1-2 | http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages```

Answer (score 29):

The `apt-cache show <Package>` shows the package descriptions of all the versions your debian installation can install (i.e. from cached list of packages available from the repos listed in `sources.list`). So I guess you could try something like (for e.g.):

```
# apt-cache show package | grep Version
Version 1.0
Version 0.9-2squeeze1
```

The `apt-cache show` would give you much more info than just versions.

Comment: Thanks, will try out. Is it possible to downgrade?

Comment: It seems to work, I just want to know if this would list packages whose versions are lower than what I currently have.

Comment: you can use apt-cache policy if only the version interest you.

Comment: @Rémi Thanks!! That command solved my next doubt, how to know where a package will come from. I was even searching already :)

Answer (score 14):

```
apt-cache policy gdb
```

Sample output:

```
gdb:
  Installed: 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2
  Candidate: 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2 0
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.7-0ubuntu3 0
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

So we see that there are two versions of GDB available:

- `7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2`
- `7.7-0ubuntu3`

Meaning of the output:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121413/understanding-the-output-of-apt-cache-policy
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/282602/what-do-the-numbers-in-the-output-of-apt-cache-policy-tell-us

Comment: Thanks, this seems more detailed than `apt-cache madison` (but harder to parse).

Comment: @CamiloMartin it's also localized. So keywords like "installed" and "candidate" will be different if the user is using a different language.

Answer (score 3):

A command that is specifically intended for this is [apt-show-versions](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=apt-show-versions).  You often have to install it, but then can run apt-show-versions -a  and it will show you the version number, the distribution (i.e. testing, stable, unstable, backports, etc.) where that can be found, and finally tell you if the version you have installed is up to date or not.

It does not give you as much information as apt-cache, but gives you pretty much what you need, as you can then install from the correct repository (using aptitude / apt-get -t) or simply install using the correct version number in the form you noted.

Comment: +1, but while testing it on my girlfriend's box with an arbitrary example, it misses one of the versions that `apt-cache` picked: http://i.imgur.com/15be7.png

Comment: That's interesting, it seems to have skipped the oldest one.  Perhaps your apt preferences are set to prefer testing?

Comment: I don't know? Where would I look to check if it prefers testing?

Comment: Check the file /etc/apt/preferences